# How can i read cookie expire date in javascript or php

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, jquery-cookie

I need to read the cookie expire date. I can use javascript and php but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Post your code for setting your cookie and we will help you read the expiration.

Answer (score 0):

**setcookie()** defines a cookie to be sent along with the rest of the HTTP headers. Like other headers, cookies must be sent before any output from your script (this is a protocol restriction). This requires that you place calls to this function prior to any output, including  and  tags as well as any whitespace.

Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed on the next page load with the $_COOKIE array. Cookie values may also exist in $_REQUEST.

Answer (score 0):

getting the expiration date of a cookie is not an easy task. The best way IMO is to set another cookie where you set the the expiration date of the first cookie as its value.

After that you just have to read the second cookie to get to the expiration date.